# GtkDrawingArea - how to make it drawable?

Tags: gtk, cairo

I'm going out of my mind a bit here.

I'm trying to draw some simple graphics on my GTK form using cairo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <cairo.h>

GtkWidget* window;
GtkWidget* darea; 


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);     
    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 390, 240);

    darea = gtk_drawing_area_new();
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), darea); 

    cairo_t *cr; 
    cr = gdk_cairo_create(darea->window);
    cairo_rectangle(cr, 0, 0, 100, 100); 
    cairo_fill(cr);


    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    gtk_main(); 

    return 0;
}
```

This compiles, but gives me

> Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_cairo_create: assertion `GDK_IS_DRAWABLE
>   (drawable)' failed

followed by a segfault.

I've been looking at the [tutorial here](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/cairographicstutorial/shapesfills/)

So I changed my code as follows, made the cairo calls occur inside the expose event.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <gtk/gtk.h>
    #include <cairo.h>

    GtkWidget* window;
    GtkWidget* darea; 

    static gboolean
    on_expose_event(GtkWidget *widget,
        GdkEventExpose *event,
        gpointer data)
    {
        cairo_t *cr; 
        cr = gdk_cairo_create(darea->window);
        cairo_rectangle(cr, 0, 0, 100, 100); 
        cairo_fill(cr);

    }    

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        gtk_init(&argc, &argv);     
        window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
        gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 390, 240);

        darea = gtk_drawing_area_new();
        gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), darea); 

        g_signal_connect(darea, "expose-event",
          G_CALLBACK(on_expose_event), NULL);


        gtk_widget_show_all(window);

        gtk_main(); 

        return 0;
    }
```

Why does this fix it? 
My understanding re: the expose is: 
the

```
g_signal_connect(darea, "expose-event", G_GCALLBACK(on_expose_event), NULL);
```

tells the program, 'when an expose event happens to darea, then call on_expose_event'. The null is where you can pass in a pointer to a struct of additional information for the function to use.

and

```
    static gboolean
    on_expose_event(GtkWidget *widget,
        GdkEventExpose *event,
        gpointer data)
    {
```

means that on_expose_event is passed a pointer to the widget that the event happened to, andin this case because it's an expose event, a pointer to a struct containing information about the expose event, and a pointer to a struct to any other information you might like to add.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Drawing on a widget with Cairo *only* works in an expose event. That is because Cairo is not like a vector drawing program where the lines and shapes are objects that are remembered and can be manipulated; Cairo just paints the shapes onto the drawing area and forgets about them.

So when you minimize and restore your window, or move another window over top of it, the shapes disappear. An expose event is generated to let you know that the shapes are gone and the widget needs to be redrawn. So you do your redrawing with Cairo in the expose event handler.

Comment: Ok, so say we have two buttons on our form, one draws a red circle on the drawing area, the other draws a blue square. 

Is the way to do this - each button click event changes a 'mode' variable, and calls gtk_widget_queue_draw(), and then the expose_events decides what to draw depending on what the mode is? 

example code: http://pastebin.com/7ZvwcCXb

Comment: In the old days you could set something to be double buffered or use save unders, I assume that's possible in GTK somehow.  You could also copy your window to a pixmap then copy back as needed.  But in XLib and Motif if I draw something, then cover and uncover it, nothing puts my drawing back.

Answer (score 3):

The warning and the consequent crash in your first code is because of the fact that `darea->window` is `NULL` i.e. `GdkWindow` (`darea->window`) has not been created yet at the point in the program when you call `gdk_cairo_create`. `GdkWindow` for the drawing area is created once the drawing area widget is *realized*. Try adding `gtk_widget_realize(darea);` before the call `gdk_cairo_create` . Also instead of directly accessing `window`, may I suggest use of the accessor function [`gtk_widget_get_window`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-get-window).
The reason why it did not assert & crash  when you have added the same code in`expose-event` callback is because `GdkWindow` associated with drawing area is already created at that point in the execution of the program.

Edit:
The reason provided above is *only* to explain why the code was *not crashing* in the `expose-event` callback & why the call `gdk_cairo_create` did not assert when the program was run. Treat the above response *just* as an explaination related to crash. Please refer [ptomato's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395111/gtkdrawingarea-how-to-make-it-drawable/9398854#9398854) for details regarding drawing mechanism

Hope this helps!

Comment: The first part of your answer is correct: `darea->window` is `NULL` when the widget is not realized. The rest is wrong: drawing _only_ works in an expose event.

Comment: @ptomato: You are right about drawing. I think I messed up the wordings in the response. I was trying to explain why the crash did not occur when the code was added in the handler & that the drawable which is `GdkWindow` is created by the time handler is called as the widget is realized. I will update the response accordingly. Thank you

Comment: Thank you for updating too! I've turned my -1 into +1.

Comment: @ptomato: That is very nice of you! Thanks again!!