# PyGTK Custom Widget doesnt redraw

Tags: python, pygtk

I have a problem updating a custom GTK+ widget: VUWidget. 
A Generator class is updating the level property of the class Section, whose subclass has a VUWidget property. The Generator class updates the values of the level properties  correctly.

```
import pygtk  
pygtk.require("2.0")  
import gtk, gtk.gdk  
import cairo  

#=========================================================================

class VUWidget(gtk.DrawingArea):
    __gtype_name__ = 'VUWidget'

    _BACKGROUND_RGB = (0., 0., 0.)
    _LEVEL_GRADIENT_BOTTOM_ORGBA = (1, 0, 1, 0, 1)
    _LEVEL_GRADIENT_TOP_ORGBA = (0, 1, 0, 0, 1)

    #_____________________________________________________________________

    def __init__(self, section):
        gtk.DrawingArea.__init__(self)      
        self.section = section      

        self.connect("configure_event", self.on_configure_event)
        self.connect("expose-event", self.OnDraw)
        self.section.connect("changed-value", self.ValueChanged)

        self.set_size_request(30,100)       
        self.realize()
        self.show()
    #_____________________________________________________________________


    def ValueChanged(self, widget, level):
        #print ("Callback %f" % self.section.GetLevel()) 

        rect = self.get_allocation()                
        self.window.invalidate_rect(rect, False)
        return False
    #_____________________________________________________________________


    def GenerateBackground(self):       
        rect = self.get_allocation()
        ctx = cairo.Context(self.source)

        ctx.set_line_width(2)
        ctx.set_antialias(cairo.ANTIALIAS_SUBPIXEL)
        pat = cairo.LinearGradient(0.0, 0.0, 0, rect.height)
        pat.add_color_stop_rgba(*self._LEVEL_GRADIENT_BOTTOM_ORGBA)
        pat.add_color_stop_rgba(*self._LEVEL_GRADIENT_TOP_ORGBA)
        ctx.rectangle(0, 0, rect.width, rect.height)
        ctx.set_source(pat)

        ctx.fill()
    #_____________________________________________________________________


    def on_configure_event(self, widget, event):
        self.source = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, self.allocation.width, self.allocation.height)
        self.GenerateBackground()

        return self.OnDraw(widget, event)
    #_____________________________________________________________________


    def OnDraw(self, widget, event):        
        ctx = self.window.cairo_create()
        ctx.save()

        rect = self.get_allocation()

        ctx.rectangle(0, 0, rect.width, rect.height)
        ctx.set_source_rgb(*self._BACKGROUND_RGB)
        ctx.fill()

        ctx.rectangle(0, rect.height * (1. - self.section.GetLevel()), rect.width, rect.height)
        ctx.clip()

        ctx.set_source_surface(self.source, 0, 0)   
        ctx.paint()

        ctx.restore()

        return False        
    #_____________________________________________________________________


    def Destroy(self):
        del self.source
        self.destroy()  
    #_____________________________________________________________________  

#=========================================================================
```

the signal is implemented in the class Section and is emitted correctly

```
__gsignals__ = {
    'changed-value' : (gobject.SIGNAL_RUN_LAST, gobject.TYPE_NONE, (gobject.TYPE_FLOAT,))
    }
```

Regards 
Ck

Comment: You forgot to include the self.OnDraw source code and the definition of the custom "value-changed" signal.

Comment: ahh, the signal, how did i forgett about it? thanks for the hint!

Comment: I would draw everything on "expose-event" and let other signal handlers only change state and call 'invalidate' afterwards, forcing the re-rendering through expose-event.

Comment: I have different drawing areas in the main window. they all change independently without any event, so i want to redraw any widget for itself and not the main window any time. If i got it right, invalidate is only callable for the complete window?! anyway i did not manage to get anything to redraw, only on startup. is there something im fundamentely doing wrong?

Comment: I should have mentioned, that I am new to python and pygtk.

Comment: Please don't edit the question willy-nilly, it is straying too much from the original question. Instead, please open another question with a stripped down example (like 40 SLOCs or soshould do). Finally, please revert this question to the last edit before the threading problem. Otherwise, this is too hard to follow, as SO is not like a traditional forum.

Comment: Yes, you are right I was a little insecure about that too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, I subclass this and provide a custom *draw* method. If there are any changes to the state, I call *invalidate*, forcing the widget to re-draw through the *expose-event*. If you need a different context, you can provide it in the *on_expose_event* 
method.

So basically, do all your drawing in **one** place only. If the widget should display something different, set the new state and re-render. Makes it easy to maintain.

```
#cairovehicle.py

import gtk

class CairoVehicle(gtk.DrawingArea):
    def __init__(self):
        gtk.DrawingArea.__init__(self)
        self.connect("expose-event", self.on_expose_event)

    def get_background(self):
        """Serves as a caching solution."""
        return self.__bg

    def set_background(self, pattern):
        """Serves as a caching solution."""
        self.__bg = pattern

    def get_brush(self):
        """Serves as a caching solution."""
        return self.__brush

    def set_brush(self, pattern):
        """Serves as a caching solution."""
        self.__brush = pattern

    def on_expose_event(self, widget, event):
        context = self.window.cairo_create()

        # Restrict cairo to the exposed area
        context.rectangle(*event.area)
        context.clip()

        self.width, self.height = self.window.get_size()

        self.draw(context)

    def on_configure_event(self, widget, event):
        """Override this in case you want to do something when 
           the widget's size changes."""

        return super(CairoVehicle, self).on_configure_event(widget, event)

    def invalidate(self):
        """Force a re-rendering of the window."""

        rect = self.get_allocation()

        # Compensate for parent offset, if any.
        parent = self.get_parent()
        if parent:
            offset = parent.get_allocation()
            rect.x -= offset.x
            rect.y -= offset.y

        self.window.invalidate_rect(rect, False)

    def draw(self, context):
        """Override this."""

        # do custom drawing here

        raise NotImplementedError()

    def make_grid(self, context, fgcolor, bgcolor, gapwidth, linewidth, 
                                                        width, height):

         context.set_source_rgba(*bgcolor)
         context.rectangle(0, 0, width, height)
         context.fill()

         context.set_source_rgba(*fgcolor)
         context.set_line_width(linewidth)

         # uneven linewidths lead to blurry displaying when set on integer
         # coordinates, so in that case move coordinates away by half a
         # pixel.
         adjust = 0.5 if linewidth % 2 else 0
         i = 1
         j = 1

         while gapwidth*i-adjust < width:
             context.move_to(gapwidth*i-adjust, 0)
             context.line_to(gapwidth*i-adjust, height)
             context.stroke()
             i += 1

         while gapwidth*j-adjust < height:
             context.move_to(0, gapwidth*j-adjust)
             context.line_to(width, gapwidth*j-adjust)
             context.stroke()
             j += 1


class Grid(CairoVehicle):
    def draw(self, context):
        context.push_group()
        self.make_grid(context, fgcolor=(0, 0, 0, 1), bgcolor=(1, 1, 1, 1),
                    gapwidth=20, linewidth=1, width=self.width,
                    height=self.height)
        self.set_background(context.pop_group())
        context.set_source(self.get_background())
        context.paint()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    w = gtk.Window()
    w.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
    w.show()

    cv = Grid()
    cv.show()
    w.add(cv)
    gtk.main()
```

**Supplemental response to comment:**

Gtk.Window and Gdk.Window are conceptually different. The first is a container that can have exactly one other widget (other container or any other widget). The second is used for drawing stuff on the display and capture events. The gdk.Window is constructed in a widget's "realize" event. Before that, it is just None in PyGtk. IMHO, it is inadvisable (don't even know if it's doable) to draw on a gtk.Window.window. Custom drawing should be done in the gtk.DrawingArea.window. That is what DrawingArea is there for.

**References:**

https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-app-devel-list/1999-January/msg00138.html
[GtkDrawingArea - how to make it drawable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395111/gtkdrawingarea-how-to-make-it-drawable)

Comment: Hi, thanks for this clearing answer! But I have the problem, that i cannot get the gdk.Window of my gtk.Window.   If I call `mainWin.window.invalidate_rect(rect, False)`,   I get the error _AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'invalidate_rect'_.   If I call `mainWin.invalidate_rect(rect, False)`,   I get the error _AttributeError: 'gtk.Window' object has no attribute 'invalidate_rect'_.  What am I doing Wrong?

Comment: You have to call those methods on something that is subclassed from gtk.DrawingArea. I'll add more detail to answer.

Comment: Hi, i feel stupid now. _The DrawingArea must be realized (i.e. the Widget methods realize() or show() have been called) to have an associated gtk.gdk.Window that can be used for drawing._ [http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/ch-DrawingArea.html]   I think I did so?! I subclassed from gdk.DrawingArea, called a `do_size_request`, afterwards `realize()/show()`. But anyway I am getting the AttributeError. Calling `drawableArea.window` from a `drawableArea` instance, has the same error. If I call `self.window.cairo_create()`, it is not NoneType. I feel like I am fundamentally missing something.

Comment: @ChristophKuhr I added a working example. But... could it be your problem is about this: http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?file=faq20.006.htp&req=show

Comment: Hell Yeah, thats some sort of my problem! I have my Generator Class threaded, but it is not a gui class. At least the first of my widgets redraws now, while the others still throw the same error. I report back...

Comment: My problem are the generator threads. They seem to loose the context of the objects that are calling them...

Comment: Now I generated some values to display from outside of python. But again, only the first widget redraws.